# Trying to redesign JMS configuration as Spring Integration: Redelivery policies

Tags: spring, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

My legacy configuration exposes a `ConnectionFactory` @Bean of type `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, with custom redelivery through  `activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(..)`.

I found out that Spring Integration DSL allows redeliveries on the handle operation as well by means of `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`, which can be configured for instance with an `ExponentialBackOffPolicy`.

I am wondering if they are triggering the same code at the lower level (not sure its a client thing or a signaling thing to the broker), and if not, whether they are equivalent and whether can I safely replace the abstract version without missing any configuratbility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; it's completely different and has nothing to do with JMS and retrying incoming deliveries.

The retry advice is generally used to retry outgoing requests, e.g. an http request, or a **send** to JMS.